# Get style from css styelsheet instead of inline style parameter

Tags: css

I'm not that experienced with css and webprogramming to start with.
I want to enable the Content-Security-Policy header for my site but it warns me about a couple of lines for using inline stuff.

The lines looks like this:

```
<li><a href="contakt" style="background:#9fa6ac;" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="https://facebook.com/companyname" target="_blank" style="background:#2e39a4;"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
```

I'm trying to figure out how I would move the **style=** parameter to the css stylesheet.

In the CSS-file, can I just add something like this?

```
facebookbutton {
    background: #2e39a4
}
phonebutton {
    background: #9fa6ac
}
```

And then do something like this?

```
<li><a href="contakt" style="css-file-somehow" .....
```

Or is this done in a totally different way?

Comment: `.facebookbutton { … }`, `<a class="facebookbutton" …>`

Comment: All in all, you are basically asking how styling elements from an external stylesheet works … so you should perhaps go read some beginner’s tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML The tag will have class attribute

```
<a href="https://facebook.com/companyname" target="_blank" class="facebookbutton"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

The Class will have styles defined in CSS like below

```
.facebookbutton{
background:#2e39a4;
```

}

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it for me.